# Best way to format the JSON content in Node.js application

Tags: node.js, json

I am working on an NODE JS based application. Trying to figure out any easy method to get my expected result. Had tried few ways, but after reframing the JSON content not able to add the key `state`.

My content JSON content is in this format

```
[
    {
        "item": {
            "property1": "aa",
            "property2": "22"
        },
        "state": {
            "item": {
                "state": "AS",
                "country": "US",
                "reason": "1"
            }
        },
        "province": {
            "item": {
                "name": "AS",
                "method": "table",
                "conf": "3"
            }
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

Requirement is to format `state` as below,

```
{
    ...
    "state": [
        {
            "item": {
                "state": "AS",
                "country": "US",
                "reason": "1"
            }
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

I want to format the `state` content. The content is expected to be an array of JSON content. After formatting `state`,  the orginal json content need to be modified with the new content of `state`. The issue faced here is after formatting not able to add the key `state` back to the orginal JSON content.Same is the expectation for `province`.

Requesting support from All...Thanks in Advance....

Below is the code i had written, but the expected result is not obtained.Can anyone help me in identifying were i have gone wrong

```
var testJson =  JSON.parse(jsonData);
var tempFinal = [];
    for(let i =0; i<testJson.length; i++) {
        let itemData = {};
        itemData.item = testJson[i].item;
        tempFinal.push(itemData);     

      var state = [];
      state.push( testJson[i].state);
      let stateData = {};
      stateData.state = state;
      tempFinal.push(stateData);
      
      var service = [];
      service.push( testJson[i].service);
      let serviceData = {};
      serviceData.service = service;
      tempFinal.push(serviceData);     
    }
```

The result obtained is

```
[
    {
        "item": {
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "portid": "22"
        }
    },
    {
        "state": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "state": "filtered",
                    "reason": "no-response",
                    "reason_ttl": "0"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "service": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "name": "ssh",
                    "method": "table",
                    "conf": "3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected is

```
[
  {
    "item": {
      "a": "a",
      "a": "a"
    },
    "state": [
      {
        "item": {
          "c": "b",
          "e": "f",
          "reason_ttl": "0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "service": [
      {
        "item": {
          "name": "q",
          "method": "table",
          "d": "e"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
```

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code? Otherwise, we cannot help you

Comment: I have reframed my contents.Hope that is fine...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
//jsonData is your original json data
jsonData.map((obj1=>{
    //updating state data
    obj1.state=[obj1.state];

}));

//finally print it.
console.log(jsonData);
```

Comment: Didn't work..i  have updated my question with the code i had written.Please help in to identify were i have gone wrong or what is the best way...

Comment: @Rahul I tried this code on my system it works fine. Can you please try this once more.